# Unity position Image over game object is not working *Fixed*

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want my UI Image to stay on the screen exactly like I sized it but just follow the game object around no matter how far or close it gets to the camera.

When I start the image disappears and it completely off the screen.

What is wrong with my code.

```
public Transform enemyTransform;
public Image followTestImage;

private void Update()
{
    Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(enemyTransform.position);
    //pos.y = Screen.height - pos.y; (removed this)
    followTestImage.transform.position = pos;
}
```

**Fixed Code**

```
private void Update()
{
    Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(enemyTransform.position);
    pos.z = 0;
    followTestImage.transform.position = pos;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure its where you are editing the `pos.y`

Comment: your image is going to move down forever. You are updating the pos.y

Comment: @Leoverload so I remove the “ pos.y = Screen.height “

Comment: @Leoverload why would it move down forever? As I can see it just changes the Y **once** per frame after retrieving a value from the `enemyTransform.position` ...

Comment: @WorlerHead what is the `pos.y = ...` line good for? What happens without it? I would probably rather use a fix value like e.g. `pos.y += followImage.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.height / 2f + 20;` or something like that

Comment: Might be because you're setting a transform position to a screen position. I think you need to convert it back to world coordinates before you apply the position.

Comment: @derHugo I thought it would convert the pos to screenPos. Let me try without it.

Comment: @WorkerHead isn't `WorldToScreenPoint` already doing that for you? ;)

Comment: Is your image in a Screen space overlay Canvas?

Comment: @derHugo Yes it is.

Comment: @Renge how would I revert it back?

Comment: @derHugo I removed that line and the same thing happened, it left the screen.

Comment: Do you have multiple Cameras?

Comment: @akaBase Just 1 main camera

Comment: Where did it go instead? What are the expected position vs the actual position? Does `pos` have the value of the expected position?

Comment: @derHugo The image in the Canvas is at (0,0,0) and it is supposed to be at (120,0,0). The Image.transform.position is at (960,540,0). The pos which is the WorldToScreenPoint is (912,649,4079,).

Comment: @derHugo so all I had to do was `pos.z = 0;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by trying to set the .z to 0 and it worked. The image stayed on top of the target.

Fixed Code

```
private void Update()
{
    Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(enemyTransform.position);
    pos.z = 0;
    followTestImage.transform.position = pos;
}
```